# REST API Client JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, rest, api, get

I have an example of `GET` method and it doesn't work for me. Any ideas why?
P.S. I am new in `HTML` and `JavaScript` so if you notice any other mistakes, say it, thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
<button type="button" onClick="MyFunction()">try it!</button>

<script>
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://my/api',
        success: function MyFunction(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);

            window.alert(obj);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call MyFunction() on button's click. 
The way you declared it, function MyFunction is a callback that is executed once the ajax call ended successfully, not the ajax call itself. 
What you want to do (I think) is:

```
<button type="button" onClick="MyFunction()">try it!</button>

<script>
    function MyFunction(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://my/api',
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                window.alert(obj);
            }
        });
</script>
```

You can see some other simple jQuery ajax() use cases at [W3C Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: Thanks! although it seems 100 per cent logical, it still doesn't work. I think I might have problems with my API then :)

Comment: @Zilvinas sharing the errors that are being shown in the browser's console would make a lot easier to troubleshoot your code.
Please consider marking this as the accepted answer if it helped you address your issue :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get any errors, the button just doesn't work. Although the API is working elsewhere, it doesn't here :)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling success call back on click. that will not for you. you should keep ajax code inside MyFunction() and called it.

```
<button type="button" onClick="MyFunction()">try it!</button>

<script>

function MyFunction(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://my/api',
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            window.alert(obj);
        }
    });

</script>
```